# Merging variables based on previouse values, SPSS

Tags: variables, merge, data-manipulation, spss

I have an spss file with education variable registered 6 times per ID number:
Education_2015
Education_2016
Education_2017
Education_2018
Education_2019
Education_2020

Each education variable has different % of missing values. The education variable has an ordinal level with a min - max values, 1-8.

What i want to create is one **EDUCATION** variable, where missing values on Education_2020 will be filled based on the registrations from previous years in that order: Education_2019, Education_2018, Education_2017, Education_2016, Education_2015.

Thanks you for help.

I have tried to do this manually, but it become impossible as the dataset contains 40 k IDs.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right you want to fill each empty year with the value of the previous one. This code will do it:

```
compute tmp=$sysmis.
do repeat edu=Education_2015 to Education_2020.
   if not missing(edu) tmp=edu.
   if missing(edu) edu=tmp.
end repeat.
```